# Como hacer login en ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

Tengo un componente llamado login, y estaba pensando en lo siguiente...

Este es mi onSubmit function la cual se ejecuta al enviar el form del login y resuelve la respuesta del servidor.

```js
onSubmit (e) {
  fetch (`http://localhost:3000/api/users/login/${this.state.username}/${this.state.password}/`, {
    method: 'POST'
  })
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => {
    if (res.success) {
      
      console.log('ok');

    }
  });
}
```

Dentro de ese if donde esta el `console.log('ok');` me gustaria por ejemplo crear una cookie que dure 1 hora, y luego saber de que manera podria verificar en los demas componentes cuando la cookie este activa o no asi permitir el ingreso al dashboard o enviarlo al login. No se si esta es la forma correcta, lei algo de JWT pero es extremadamente dificil para alguien nuevo en esto y la verdad este sitio no necesita demaciada seguridad. Que me recomiendan hacer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Dentro de ese if donde esta el `console.log('ok')` me gustaria por ejemplo crear una cookie que dure 1 hora

Las cookies se crean en el servidor y son enviadas al cliente, así, con cada petición se envían implícitas.

Ejemplo de login en Express:

**Nota:** se necesita instalar los middleware [`cookie-parser`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-parser) y [`cookie-session`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-session)`.

```
// registramos el middleware
app.use(session({
  secret: 'Sup3R$ecR3t'
  cookie: {
    httpOnly: true,
    expires: new Date(Date.now() + 60000)
  }
});
```

La forma recomendada es guardar la información directamente en memoria.

**Nota:** se necesita instalar los middleware [`cookie-parser`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-parser) y [`express-session`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session)`.

```
app.use(session({
  secret: 'Sup3R$ecR3t',
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: {
    expiress: new Date(Date.noe() + 60000),
    httpOnly: true
  }
});
```

En ésta forma, los datos de sesión se guardan en memoria, ya no en una cookie como sucede con el ejemplo anterior. Lo único que se guarda en una cookie aquí es el id de la sesión del usuario.

Una vez añadido el middleware de sesión, cuando se loguee un usuario y se toque el objeto `session` de `request` empezará su sesión.

```
app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  let { email, password } = req.body;
  UserRepository.login(email, password)
    .then(logged => {
      if(logged) { // login correcto
        res.session.user = { email };
        res.jsonp({ success: true });
      } else {
        res.jsonp({
          success: false,
          message: 'Email o contraseña incorrecta'
        });
      }
});
```

---

> No se si esta es la forma correcta, lei algo de JWT pero es extremadamente dificil para alguien nuevo en estoy y la verdad este sitio **no necesita** demaciada seguridad

En ese caso te es suficiente usar cookies. Por otro lado, JWT no es difícil, en realidad es bastante sencillo, solo consta de crear un token y enviarlo al cliente como con las cookies, así, en cada petición éste token será enviado al servidor.

> ¿Qué es JWT?

JWT es un estándar abierto ([RFC 7519](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519)) que define una manera segura de establecer comunicación entre dos partes. La importancia de éste estándar es que la información que se comparta es firmada digitalmente, lo que implica un plus importante de seguridad. De hecho, JWT se puede firmar usando el clásico algoritmo [`HMAC`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC) o con una clave [`RSA`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA).

Cuando se usa JWT, la autorización se guarda en el cliente, generalmente en `localStorage` y en cada petición que se haga al servidor es enviado en la cabecera `Authorization` con el valor `Bearer <token>`.

El siguiente ejemplo simula un login usando [`jsonwebtoken`](http://npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken).

Primero creamos una función que cree un token:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
  
function createToken (user) {
  return jwt({
    user,
    secret: 'MySecret',
    expiresInMinutes: 60
  });
}
```

Segundo hacemos el login, si éste es exitoso, se genera el token y se envía al cliente:

```
app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  UserRepository.login(email, password)
    .then(user => {
      if (user) {
        res.jsonp({
          success: true,
          user,
          token: createToken(user)
        });
      }
    });
```

Cuando el usuario acceda a cualquier recurso (sea API o lo que sea), se decodifica el token que está implícito en la cabecera `Authorization` y se compara. Para ésto podemos implementar un middleware que lo haga en cada petición.

```
app.use('/app', (req, res, next) => {
  // no hay cabecera Authorization, por ende,
  // el usuario no se ha logueado
  if (!req.headers.authoritzation) {
    // redirigimos hacia login
    return res.status(403).redirect('/login');
  }
  const token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[0];
  jwt.decode(token, 'MySecret', (err, decoded) => {
    if(err) {
      return res.status(403).redirect('/login');
    }
    next(); // payload verificado, prosigue ;)
  });
});
```

Cuando el token expire, el token no será enviado en la petición y el middleware redigirá hacia `/login`.

---

Algunas ventajas de JWT son:

- Fácil escalado horizontal
- Útil para implementar APIs RESTful seguras
- Tienen un mecanismo de "auto expiración" integrado

Comment: Gracias guz, como ya sabras yo uso un backend en node haciendo de rest api y el front-end en react, en caso de usar JWT, no tengo que instalar los midelware? Y Este ultimo codigo que verifica el auth del header, iria en la section Landing donde llamo a todos los componentes, o en cada uno de los componentes que desee sean privados? Recuerda que cada componente lo tengo routeado (Ej. /login, /categories, /demos)

Comment: El middleware donde se verifica en token debe mapear las rutas que deben ser privadas. Por ejemplo, en tu caso, que es una aplicación con login, todas las rutas, a excepción de `/login` deben ser protegidas por el middleware.

Comment: No logro entender que parte de tu expilcacion va en el servidor en node y cual en react :s

Comment: La authorización se hace obviamente en el backend, el front no tiene nothing to do con eso.

Comment: Osea que cada vez que ingreso por ejemplo a /categories tengo que hacer un request al backend para preguntarle si la sesion de ese usuario esta aun activa? Como seria esto?

Comment: Por lo que veo estás usando React Router. ¿cierto?

Comment: Exactamente master ;)

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51959/discussion-between-guzgarcia-and-santiago-dantuoni).